# In WordPress - PHP mail() responding with "502 Bad Gateway Error" inspite of having success message while email is working fine

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using mail() in WordPress. But in spite of having success message I am getting:

> 502 Bad Gateway Error

All code is working fine and mail() is working correctly, but in spite of showing a success message it is showing "502 Bad Gateway Error". How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you please share the code which you are using for sending the mail...?? Some help about 502 error here... http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/502error.htm

Comment: thank you hiren but this is not much helpful...i have installed easy smtp plugin and while using php mail() i am getting "502 Bad Gateway" error and sometimes email is sent and success message is displaying..can you please tell me what would be the issue?